# Can I embed a cloud object on my website without the need for viewers to register?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

When I use `EmbedCode[CloudDeploy["hello, world"]]` and put the result to my website, only a registration form appears.

Comment: Read well the docs of [`CloudDeploy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudDeploy.html). Look for the option `Permissions` ...

Comment: `Permissions -> "Public"`